# Get html from a selected tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

So i want to get html of a selected tab when i press OK.  But something doesnt work. What am i missing?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "discription",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function getHTML()
{

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getHTML"}, function(response) {
        if(respond.method="getHTML"){               
            alert(response.html);  
      }
    });
});

}
</script>
 <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick ="getHTML()" />
</body>
```

**contentscript.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.method == "getHTML"){
            sendResponse({html: document.all[0].outerHTML});
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It's hard to see the problem as it is. 1) What do you mean by "does not work"? What do you see. 2) Have you tried debugging your extension? did you come up with a more focused point-of-failure ?

Comment: there is no alert message even, when i ckick ok nothing happens

Comment: have you tried debugging it with the [chrome debugger](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two errors:
1) popup.html is checking for "respond" instead of "response".
2) popup.html is checking for response.method to be "getHTML", but the content_script never sets the "method" field.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use the [chrome debugger](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) to see what's going on. It'll save you a lot of time in future.

Comment: Well done! i hope you move forward swiftly. I'm also going to delete my older comments to leave this question "clean" for future users. I suggest you do the same :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.all` is undefined in Google Chrome!

Replace it with `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML`:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.method == "getHTML"){
            sendResponse({html: document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML});
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct - trying document.all and document.all[0] on the chrome debugger seems to work perfectly. Even otherwise, he can probably use `document.documentElement` instead.